# Constantly setting animation on TextView and Constantly changing text on TextView Using “run” Method and Handler

Tags: android, textview, android-animation

I have a string array that contains the string values, it displays on the TextView after some time one by one. It stops on the last index of the array. I want to start again changing the text of the TextView from index zero to last index.

I have an animation that is the applied to the above mentioned TextView. The animation showing its result only once on starting time, after that it does not showing its result.
Here is my Java code.

```
Animation animMove;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    intelStoryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intel_story_textview);

    doTask();

    animMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.move);
}

public void doTask() {

    final String[] my_string = {"Relief Rally", "OEDC Upgrades ", "US Fed to HIKE ", "Probability "};
    final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            animMove.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            intelStoryTextView.setAnimation(animMove);
            intelStoryTextView.setText(my_string[i++]);

            if (i == my_string.length) {
                i = 0;
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);

            } else {

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 5);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Here is my animation code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="70%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        />

</set>
```

Comment: start your animation then

Comment: and then always call `postDelayed`

Comment: Try to add `animMove.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);` to your animation.

Comment: @Rami whent put this code. it shows me error  'code'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.animation.Animation.setRepeatCount(int)' on a null object reference'code'

Comment: Your *animMove* is null, where you initialize it? please post the full code.

Comment: @Rami Now animation does not working properly, it blinks and moving rapidly.

Comment: First, you need to initialize `animMove` before calling `doTask();` to avoid NPE. Then increase the duration if you want to slow down the animation.

Comment: @Rami The problem is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code below, i've tested it and it should work fine:

Your *move.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart" /> <!-- i've added repeatCount and repeatMode attr -->

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="70%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"/> <!-- i've added repeatCount and repeatMode attr -->
</set>
```

Your activity:

```
    AnimationSet animMove; // i changed Animation to AnimationSet because i need the list of animations
    TextView intelStoryTextView;
    String[] my_string = {"Relief Rally", "OEDC Upgrades ", "US Fed to HIKE ", "Probability "};
    int position = 0; // a counter for your list of strings

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        intelStoryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intel_story_textview);

        animMove = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.move);

        // I get an animation from the animations list (i choose randomly the first one)
        Animation alphaAnim = animMove.getAnimations().get(0);
        // I add a listener to this animation to update text when repeating
        alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // here i do the update
                if (position >= my_string.length) {
                    position = 0;
                }

                intelStoryTextView.setText(my_string[position]);
                position++;
            }
        });

        // I start the animation
        intelStoryTextView.startAnimation(animMove);

    }
```

**Update**

If you want to stop an infinite animation for a while before repeating it, you may use a `Handler` instead of `repeartCount` tag:

*move.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="70%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"/>
</set>
```

*Your activity*

```
    Animation mAnimMove;
    TextView mIntelStoryTextView;
    String[] mMy_string = {"Relief Rally", "OEDC Upgrades ", "US Fed to HIKE ", "Probability "};
    int mPosition = 0;
    int mInterval = 5000;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mIntelStoryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intel_story_textview);

        mAnimMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.move);

        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (mPosition >= mMy_string.length) {
                    mPosition = 0;
                }

                mIntelStoryTextView.setText(mMy_string[mPosition]);
                mPosition++;
                mIntelStoryTextView.startAnimation(mAnimMove);

                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mInterval);
            }
        };

        mRunnable.run();
    }
```

Comment: Your code is useful. But i also want to stay the TextView for some milliseconds at android:toXDelta="0%p".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not use 'move' as animation name. This could override android default move animation and broke default bottom sheet dialog animation.